# Passing secrets to NixOps logical network specification

Tags: nix, nixops

I am deploying a web application to AWS with NixOps. The application requires some environment variables to be set. I can achieve this with something similar to the following:

```
{
  network.description = "Web server";

  webserver = { config, pkgs, ... }: {
    environment.systemPackages = [ webserver ];
    networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 ];

    systemd.services.webserver = {
      description = "Example webapp";

      environment = {
        SECRET_KEY = "SECRET_VALUE";
      }
    };
  };
}
```

I want this file to be checked into my source control system, but I do not want the `SECRET_VALUE` to be stored in the clear if I can help it.

Is there a way to read these values in from a GPG encrypted file when they're needed for a deploy? Or is there some other method? Or do I need to encrypt the whole file?

Comment: Although not really part of NixOps, you could `import` your secrets from a `git-crypt`ed file. You should probably not put secrets in the world-readable nix store like in your example. You can use [NixOps keys](https://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#idm140737318276736) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd use NixOps keys, since their purpose is to provide sensitive data to your app while storing such content outside of the Nix store.

> Files in /nix/store/ are readable by every user on that host, so
>   storing secret keys embedded in nix derivations is insecure. To
>   address this, nixops provides the configuration option
>   deployment.keys, which nixops manages separately from the main
>   configuration derivation for each machine. -
>   https://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#idm140737318276736

To be more specific, in your case Nix will create a systemd unit file for your webserver service and that file, which is stored in `/nix/store`, will have your SECRET_KEY in it.

But if using environment variables is a must, you can use `builtins.readFile` to read the environment variable's value from an external file. The file will need to be present when you build/deploy, so you'd secure the data either by NOT storing it in the Git repo, or using transparent encryption (ex. `git-crypt`) as Robert suggested.

```
{
  network.description = "Web server";

  webserver = { config, pkgs, ... }: {
    environment.systemPackages = [ webserver ];
    networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 ];

    systemd.services.webserver = {
      description = "Example webapp";

      environment = {
        SECRET_KEY = builtins.readFile ./secret.data;
      }
    };
  };
}
```